# how to have multiple textbox for a ajax calendar control by button_Click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, button, calendar

i have this ajax calendar control, but i click on the btnDate3 it will add another row of the textbox which allow me to select date from the calendar control again, so if i click submit, it will retrieve each textbox date from each row after you Add
 so basically a user can click on the Add button then , it will add another row of textbox which have the same function

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate1" />
            <ajaxtoolkit:calendarextender  runat="server" ID="calExtender1" 
                                        TargetControlID="txtDate1" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="CheckDateEalier" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
 <asp:Button ID="btnDate3" Text="Add" Width="20px" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="submit" Text="Submit" Width="20px" runat="server" />
```

this is the javascript i use to check the date

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckDateEalier(sender,args) {
        if (sender._selectedDate < new Date()) {
             alert("You cannot select a day before today or today!");
             sender._selectedDate = new Date(); 
             // set the date back to the today
            // sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
             sender._textbox.set_Value(null)
         }
     }
</script>
```